# How to use CONCAT_WS instead of FULL-TEXT SEARCH

Tags: php, mysql, concat-ws

### MySQL

```
+----+-------------------+----------+--------------+
| id | address           | city     | state        |      
+----+-------------------+----------+--------------+
| 1  | 13000 highway 244 | keystone | south dakota |
+----+-------------------+----------+--------------+
```

(btw, I left out some columns to make it easier)

### PHP

```
$string = mysql_real_escape_string('13000 highway 244 south dakota');

$a = mysql_query("

    SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE

    CONCAT_WS(' ', `address`, `city`, `state`) LIKE '%$string%'

");
```

The above search query doesn't return any results, only the following `values` would work:

- 13000 highway 244 keystone south dakota
- 13000 highway 244 keystone
- keystone south dakota

However, I also want to get the following `values` to work:

- 13000 highway 244 south dakota
- 13000 highway keystone
- south dakota highway keystone
- etc.

Is that even possible without relying on `full-text search`?

Comment: The solution to this would be a rather intensive keyword search that doesn't rely on finding the existence of a string within another string. Your best two solutions are to either use more than one input to search on a per-field basis, or to use a textarea and use newlines (`\n`) as a separator for each chunk of info, eg. `$string = explode(PHP_EOL, $textarea)`; Why? because `CONCAT_WS` isn't appropriate for what should be a simple query.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it code more explicitly like this?

```
$address = mysql_real_escape_string('13000 highway 244');
$city = mysql_real_escape_string('keystone');
$state = mysql_real_escape_string('south dakota');

$a = mysql_query( '

    SELECT * 
      FROM `table` 
     WHERE (   ( address = ' . $address . ' )
           AND ( city    = ' . $city    . ' )
           AND ( state   = ' . $state   . ' )
           )
        OR ( state   = ' . $state   . ' )
             .. probably more alternatives ...
');
```

Comment: Well, I have just one input field, and I wouldn't be able to tell whether the user typed in the address, city, or state. And I also don't want to save them all in just one field in the db. But thanks anyways!

Comment: Yes, I'd rather just see one input field than three or more. Same goes for Google Maps, for example. I can't imagine looking for a place on Google Maps, and having to type in the address, city, state in separate input fields. But thanks for your advice :) I guess I'll just have to use full-text search then.

Answer (score 0):

before passing the string to query replace the spaces with wildcard so even "130 dakoda" would work

`$string = str_replace( array('*', '?', ' '), array('%', '_', '%'), $string); //Change norm wildcards to mysql format and replace spaces with wildcards`